# Analyzing binary data with repeated measures across different levels in R

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, binary-data, cochran-q

I have this data frame: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGh1z.png
It is the binary recorded responses (repeated measures) of subjects to 4 different tests under 2 environmental conditions (2x4 factorial design with repeated measures on both factors).

I am looking for any statistically significant difference that changes in condition might have on the subject's responses and account for the different tests and repeated measures.
I tried to conduct a Cochran's Q test in R. This is the first time I am trying this test and having multiple observations per block is not helping and I am constantly facing errors. The other solution that comes to my mind is to change the response variable to the percentage of times that the subjects' responses were "1" to each test in four repeated measures. So this way the binary response will change to numerical and I could do a repeated measures ANOVA maybe?
I would appreciate your thoughts!

Comment: Please show your data (or at least a sample) directly in the question; the linked image is illegible at least on my system. You can do that in the editing mode by putting the data between two lines each of which contains "```"; see the help for "Code" for Body text. It would also help if you could show the functions that you have called and errors that your attempts so far have generated.